# Sending An Android Codename One Build with a native library I'm getting DexIndexOverflowException

Tags: android, codenameone

I'm integrating a native 3rd party library into Codename One and I'm getting the following error during build at the bottom of the build log:

```
       [dx] Merged dex A (1099 defs/2414.7KiB) with dex B (1 defs/0.4KiB). Result is 1100 defs/3068.7KiB. Took 0.9s
       [dx] Result compacted from 4131.2KiB to 2416.3KiB to save 1714.8KiB
       [dx] Merged dex A (1100 defs/3068.7KiB) with dex B (4 defs/3.5KiB). Result is 1104 defs/2416.3KiB. Took 0.8s
       [dx] Result compacted from 7298.5KiB to 5991.1KiB to save 1307.4KiB
       [dx] Merged dex A (1104 defs/2416.3KiB) with dex B (4118 defs/3577.8KiB). Result is 5222 defs/5991.1KiB. Took 0.9s
       [dx] 
       [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
       [dx] com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:283)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
       [dx] 

BUILD FAILED
/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:888: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:890: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:902: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:283: null returned: 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Androids DEX APK format has a 64k method count limit that's easy to exceed once you start working with multiple large libraries. Unfortunately working around it with Ant is impossible so you will need to switch to the new [Gradle based build system](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/material-icons-background-music-geofencing-gradle.html) (this will be the default with Codename One 3.3 currently slated for January 2016).

Prior to 3.3 you can just define the build hint `android.gradle=true`.

You will then need to define the build hint `android.multidex=true` to solve that specific error.